# Plugin based on jquery plugin template

Tags: jquery

In my jQuery class I learnt about the jquery plugin template over here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/91b4eb05b18f3038a6f8a34c41435c4d2702c0d0/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js

I understood some concepts like why `;(function ( $, window, document, undefined )` is used and how to create the defaults etc

```
var pluginName = "defaultPluginName",
                defaults = {
                propertyName: "value"
        };
```

however the example the teacher gave us on this template about creating a plugin to highlight a div element, went over my head. We did not get the demo code to understand it later.

Can any one over here create a plugin that highlights a div element based on the template and explain the same step by step - like how to use the defaults, the plugin construction and create the actual plugin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by highlight? Like a background color? Or like jQuery UI's animated highlight?

Comment: yes the plugin allows me to specify just a background color and a custom font. If not the defaults can be speficied in the plugin

Comment: Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5h68swxq/2/ Basically, the default properties are set in the constructor at `this._defaults = defaults`. However, the settings object extends the default object at `this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );` so that you don't overwrite the default settings for other elements. At initialization, you apply the settings with jQuery's `css` function.

Comment: thanks @arao6 I will check it and let you know if I face any issues. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Expanded on my comment with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery plugin template does a number of things:

The boilerplate sets the `$` sign to jQuery to avoid plugin conflicts (e.g. Prototype also uses `$` like jQuery, so how do you make sure your plugin uses jQuery and not something else? You pass jQuery into an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like so):

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.yourPlugin = function() {
    // Do stuff!
  };
})( jQuery ); // pass jQuery so the $ is jQuery and not something else in the function
```

But that doesn't solve all of our problems, since `undefined` in ECMAScript 3 may not be `undefined` (i.e., it is mutable—it can be modified by other scripts), so we add another parameter:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {
  $.fn.yourPlugin = function() {
    // Do stuff!
  };
})( jQuery ); // note that we're not passing any value to make it truly undefined
```

The boilerplate also passes `window` and `document` as local variables so that they are resolved a little faster, and it also adds a bit of code so that the plugin can be chained like other jQuery objects. Now we end up at the boilerplate code:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

        var pluginName = "highlighter";

        var defaults = {
        };

        function Plugin ( element, options ) {
                this.element = element;
                this.settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
                this._defaults = defaults;
                this._name = pluginName;
                this.init();
        }

        $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
                init: function () {
                }
        });

        // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
        // preventing against multiple instantiations
        $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
                this.each(function() {
                        if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
                        }
                });

                // chain jQuery functions
                return this;
        };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Now let's explore how to highlight a div and change the font. First, you can extend your default settings with some properties:

```
// Here we create the defaults:
var defaults = {
    bgColor: 'yellow',
    font: 'normal small-caps normal 16px/1.4 Georgia'
};
```

In the plugin wrapper, when your plugin is instantiated, it also calls the `init()` function:

```
// "options" parameter may contain the user's values to override defaults
$.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
    // for each selected element
    this.each(function() {
        // ...
        // When "new Plugin()" -> init() is called in the function, see "function Plugin()"
        $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ) );
    }
}
```

The boilerplate also does one other important thing: it stores the user's settings in `this.settings` instead of `this.defaults` so that the plugin's default settings aren't overwritten by a user's custom settings.

The `new Plugin()` calls the `init()` function where we can work our magic. To access the default or custom settings, we simply need to access `this.settings`:

```
init: function () {
    // Set the highlight and font.
    $(this.element).css({ 
        'background-color': this.settings.bgColor,
        'font': this.settings.font
    });
}
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5h68swxq/2/).

Comment: You should volunteer to write documentation for jQuery. Fantastic explanation!